# esbuild - Build and bundle source directory into single output file

Tags: esbuild

I feel like I may be missing something obvious here, but I can't seem to figure out how to build all JS files in source directory and bundling them into a bundled distribution that can be referenced from the browser. Here is my setup:

Directory

```
dist/
src/
  index.js
  test1.js
  test2.js
index.html
```

test1.js

```
export function helloFrom1() {
    console.log('Hello from 1');
}
```

test2.js

```
export function helloFrom2() {
    console.log('Hello from 2');
}
```

index.js

```
import './test1.js';
import './test2.js';
```

I'm invoking the build using the following command:

`./node_modules/.bin/esbuild src/index.js --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=dist --watch`

After executing the above, `dist/index.js` is created with the following contents:

```
(() => {
})();
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

Obviously, missing the contents of `test1.js` and `test2.js`. I'm assuming it stems from the fact that I'm not actually referencing anything from `test1.js` or `test2.js`, but what I'd ideally like to be able to do is reference it from the HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>

        <script src="./dist/index.js"></script>

        <script>
            helloFrom1();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.